# How to remove user form SPGroup using SPServices

Tags: 2013, spservices, spgroup

I am using below code for removing user from particular group using SPServices.

In complete function alert is showing success, but in XData it is displaying  `User does not exist or is not unique`. I don't know what I am missing in this code.

Any idea?

```
 function removeUserFromGroup(user, groupname) {

                var con = confirm('Are you sure to delete this user');
                if (con == true) {

                            $().SPServices({
                                operation: "RemoveUserFromGroup",
                                groupName: groupname,
                                userLoginName: user,
                                async: false,
                                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                                    alert("success");
                                }

                            });
                            //return true;   
                        }
                else
                    return false;
            }
```

Comment: How are you passing "user" value ... can you provide test values

Comment: Is your user value in this format : DOMAIN\\User_Alias ?

Comment: am getting login name like this "i:0#.w|inashok.kulkarni"

Comment: for test purpose try to input the user value as "DOMAIN\\User_Alias" format to test the code.

Comment: for test puporse am passing "IN\\ashok.k", then also am facing same error

Comment: refer this post for similar issue and resolution - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139742/help-with-removeuserfromgroup-using-spservices

Comment: yesterday i tried using above link also ,its not working for me, for example my user  userLoginName is "i:0#.w|in\spserverfarm.qa"